# Reindex stuck at processing even after resetting in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, indexer

My `indexer:reindex` process for Design config grid, Customer Grid, and Catalog Search always stuck at processing:

[image]

i already reset the indexer, but when i run `indexer:reindex` again, it stucks at processing

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
```

and the same goes when i try to invalid the indexer from db

```
update indexer_state set status = 'invalid'
```

Comment: How much data you have in your system?

Comment: @SukumarGorai what data?

Comment: Orders, customers, products etc are data.

Comment: @SukumarGorai 8789 products ,  2139 orders, 769 customers

Comment: have you tried `reindexing` after `reset`?

Comment: `php bin/magento indexer:reset`  

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: @magefms the result is still the same, stuck at processing for those 3

Comment: are you on production mode ? have you tried `di:compile` before reindexing? 
or try to update on save and not by schedule

Comment: First increase the timeout of your ssh connection and increase the memory_limit then run `php bin/magento indexer:reset` and then run `php bin/magento memory_limit=10G indexer:reindex`

Comment: Check if you have any cron running every minute and if it relates with those reindexes .

Comment: @SukumarGorai still stuck

Comment: Did you increase the memory limit and ssh timeout?

Comment: @YlgenGuxholli i have my cron running

Comment: @SukumarGorai yes

Comment: @Lolz you may had setup any crons , that gets those indexer running , try to increase the time of the cron for those , and test again.

Comment: @YlgenGuxholli when i checked the `cron_schedule` table , jobs for `indexer_reindex_all_invalid` status always **missed** and the description is **Too late for the schedule**

Comment: added some description on the answer below @Lolz

Comment: @YlgenGuxholli the cron is not the main problem, but my indexer:reindex always stuck at processing, thats the main problem

Comment: @Lolz it should be because they are related , for example if you do a cron update to products , the indexer will run too.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using MariaDB, you should check Magento's recommendation: [here](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/prerequisites/database-server/mysql.html?lang=en)

> Reindexing on MariaDB 10.4 and 10.6 takes more time compared to previous MariaDB or MySQL versions. To speed up reindexing, we recommend setting these MariaDB configuration parameters:

> optimizer_switch='rowid_filter=off'

> optimizer_use_condition_selectivity = 1

Access to your database and set configuration:

```
set global optimizer_switch='rowid_filter=off';
set global optimizer_use_condition_selectivity = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any cron running every minute and if it relates with those reindexes .
If any of crons is related to those indexer that are running , try to increase the time of the cron for those , and test again.
Are you running on a Magento 2 Enterprice or Community ?

Try to increase **Schedule Ahead for**   option and then run `php bin/magento cron:run --group=index`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When i inspect mysql process from `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` at mysql terminal, turns out there are too many lock on my magento 2 database

in order to fix this i need to stop and then start mysql again:

```
service mysqld stop
service mysqld start
```